# How do you use cin.fail() to validate a string in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to validate if an input that is supposed to be a string is entered as a string of letters and not numbers. Here's what I have:

```
    // Manufacturer
    cout << "Enter the manufacturer: " << endl;
    string newManufacturer;
    cin >> newManufacturer;
    while (cin.fail()) {
        cout << "Error! Invalid input." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the manufacturer: " << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cin >> newManufacturer;
    }
    obj1.setManufacturer(newManufacturer);
```

Comment: Strings can contain all characters including numbers. If you want to exclude numbers you will need to check the string for them yourself.

Comment: In order to check whether an individual character is a number or not, you can use [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit). In order to check whether an individual character is a letter or not, you can use [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)

Comment: Just as a side note: Instead of duplicating the lines `cout << "Enter the manufacturer: " << endl;` and `cin >> newManufacturer;`, you can use an infinite loop `for(;;)` (which is equivalent to `while(true)`) and have the line `if ( !cin.fail() ) break;` inside that infinite loop. That way, no code duplication will be necessary.

Comment: "is entered as a string of letters and not numbers" -- Does the string have to consist of characters that are all 1. letters, or 2. not numbers? For example, is the string allowed to contain the following characters? `&^$#+-(`

Comment: What is the actual rule that tells you whether a manufacturer's name is valid or not? Real-world companies exist with numbers in their names, for example 3M.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string newManufacturer;

    for (;;) //infinite loop
    {
        //prompt user for input
        std::cout << "Enter the manufacturer: " << std::flush;
        std::cin >> newManufacturer;

        //fall through to label "input_invalid" if stream extraction failed
        if ( !std::cin.fail() )
        {
            //verify that input consists completely of letters
            for ( char &c : newManufacturer )
            {
                if ( !std::isalpha( c ) )
                    goto input_invalid;
            }
            break;
        }

    input_invalid:
        //print error message and prepare stream for next input attempt
        std::cout << "Error! Invalid input." << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore( 256, '\n' );
    }

    std::cout << "The input is valid." << std::endl;

    //do something with the input
}
```

Normally, you should not use `goto` statements, if they can be avoided. However, I see no way to avoid it, without incurring significant code duplication.